# Angular2: How to resolve Component is not part of any NgModule ...?

Tags: javascript, angular

I am new to angular 2. Currently I am still a learner. My angular 2 version is 2.1. I have a simple file structure as below:

[image]

The content of **app.ts** is as below:

```
import { Component } from "@angular/core";

@Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    template: `
        <a>Hello</a>
        <a>About</a>
`})
export class App { }
```

well, it is really simple. The content of **helloSolarSystem.ts** is as below:

```
import { NgModule, Type } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { platformBrowserDynamic } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';

import { App } from 'components/app';

let INITIAL_COMPONENTS = { App };

@NgModule({
    imports: [ BrowserModule
    ],
    declarations: INITIAL_COMPONENTS,
    bootstrap: [App]
})
class HelloSolarSystemModule extends Type{}

platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(HelloSolarSystemModule);
```

It's quite simple too, the content of **config.js** is as below:

```
System.config({
//use typescript for compilation
transpiler: 'typescript',
//typescript compiler options
typescriptOptions: {
    emitDecoratorMetadata: true
},
paths: {
    //'npm:': 'https://unpkg.com/'
    'npm:': 'node_modules/'
},
//map tells the System loader where to look for things
map: {

    'app': './src',
    'components': './components',
    'config': './config',

    '@angular/core': 'npm:@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js',
    '@angular/common': 'npm:@angular/common/bundles/common.umd.js',
    '@angular/compiler': 'npm:@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js',
    '@angular/platform-browser': 'npm:@angular/platform-browser/bundles/platform-browser.umd.js',
    '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic': 'npm:@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/bundles/platform-browser-dynamic.umd.js',
    '@angular/http': 'npm:@angular/http/bundles/http.umd.js',
    '@angular/router': 'npm:@angular/router/bundles/router.umd.js',
    '@angular/forms': 'npm:@angular/forms/bundles/forms.umd.js',

    '@angular/core/testing': 'npm:@angular/core/bundles/core-testing.umd.js',
    '@angular/common/testing': 'npm:@angular/common/bundles/common-testing.umd.js',
    '@angular/compiler/testing': 'npm:@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler-testing.umd.js',
    '@angular/platform-browser/testing': 'npm:@angular/platform-browser/bundles/platform-browser-testing.umd.js',
    '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/testing': 'npm:@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/bundles/platform-browser-dynamic-testing.umd.js',
    '@angular/http/testing': 'npm:@angular/http/bundles/http-testing.umd.js',
    '@angular/router/testing': 'npm:@angular/router/bundles/router-testing.umd.js',

    'rxjs': 'npm:rxjs'
},
//packages defines our app package
packages: {
    app: {
        main: 'helloSolarSystem.ts',
        defaultExtension: 'ts'
    },

    components : {
        defaultExtension: 'ts'
    },

    rxjs: {
        defaultExtension: 'js'
    }
}
```

});

Not too much magic. However, when I run the index.html in browser, the console will return:
**zone.js:232 Error: (SystemJS) Component App is not part of any NgModule or the module has not been imported into your module.(…)**

Anybody know why?

Comment: not an expert, but may be this link can help https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/11292 .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using an array for the declaration values instead of an object:

```
let INITIAL_COMPONENTS = [App];

@NgModule({
    imports: [BrowserModule],
    declarations: INITIAL_COMPONENTS,
    bootstrap: [App]
})
class HelloSolarSystemModule extends Type{}
```